# Nasty Object on XML Serialize

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Hey there i'm trying Deserialize an nasty object from a xml response, all works fine my array list is returned fine, but all objects inside is null.I will post a classes with annotations and the xml, but if i'm change an annotation the Deserialization doesn't work.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "DocumentElement", Namespace = "")]
public class dados {

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "dados", Namespace = "")]
    public positionData[] Position ;

}

public class positionData {
    [XmlText]
    public string Placa { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("dataini")]
    public DateTime dataini { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("datafim")]
    public DateTime datafim { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("tipo")]
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("idpontoreferencia")]
    public long idpontoreferencia { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("nome")]
    public string nome { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Data")]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }     
}
```

The XML

```
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
<dados>
    <![CDATA[<Placa>LLV6386 </Placa><Latitude>-22,91572</Latitude><Longitude>-43,09471</Longitude><dataini>15/08/2017 11:12:35</dataini><datafim></datafim><tipo>P</tipo><idpontoreferencia>76749</idpontoreferencia><nome></nome><Data>15/08/2017 11:12:36</Data>]]>
</dados>
```

The error [The erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auPB1.jpg)

Comment: The are no errors.  Just null data value.  The properties are not attributes so why are you labeling the properties with XmlAttribute?

Comment: Just change XmlAttribute to  XmlElement and no more erros even null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fix, the answer is simple, just change annotations of objects to         [XmlElement("NameOfProprietiesOnXML")]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few problems here. First off you got CDATA in your XML, this is going to be interpreted as text, not XML, so you need to either remove the CDATA tag or set up the dados class to just contain text & extract the text to then build out the xml directly from it.

Once you have the straightened out, it doesn't look like the information inside dados is actually an array of any sort. You should just be able to add those positionData attributes directly to the dados class. If you want them in a seperate class your xml is going to have to look like

```
<dados>
 <positionData>
  <placa></placa>
  ...
  <Latitude></Latitude>
 </positionData>
</dados>
```

additionally if you do this you'll want to add the xmlroot and serializable attributes to positiondata's class definition as well as the xmlarrayitem attribute to positiondata member on dados.

Comment: Tankyou for fast response, but if i'm add that annotation the object becomes null =/

Comment: post the xml you're deserializing. if something is null, it's typically a mapping issue

Comment: Yap i'm have data with null values, how can i'm fix that? See the xml...

Comment: <DocumentElement xmlns="">
 <dados>
  <Placa>LLV6386 </Placa>
  <Latitude>-22,91572</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-43,09471</Longitude>
  <dataini>15/08/2017 11:12:35</dataini>
  <datafim/>
  <tipo>P</tipo>
  <idpontoreferencia>76749</idpontoreferencia>
  <nome/>
  <Data>15/08/2017 11:12:36</Data>
 </dados>
</DocumentElement>

Comment: what happens if you take the CDATA out?